# How to use logging filter without passing resulting logger as an extra argument to every function?

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging Filters to provide contextual information for logging statements.

```
import logging

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):

        record.client_id = 12345
        return True

FORMAT = "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s:{\"client_id\": %(client_id)s}"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)
f = ContextFilter()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(f)
```

I want that in every function  the extra parameter "client_id" is logged without passing the logger explicitly as an argument.
I tried

```
def h():
   logging.info("test")
h()
```

but I get `"ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'client_id'"`

The following does work:

```
def h(logger):
   logger.info("test")
h()
```

but I am to lazy to add to every function an extra argument. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `logging.info()` you are using the root logger, which doesn't have your filter. If you added

```
logging.getLogger().addFilter(f)  # logging.getLogger() gets root logger
```

then your `logging.info()` call won't raise the error.